# VB.NET Shell() Impersonate

Tags: vb.net, impersonation

I'm calling CMD.exe after I succeed impersonate as another user.

After cmd shows up.
Then I check by code `echo %username%` it's back to my user again.

In debug mode, I call WindowsIdentity, it's success as another user.

Here's some code for my impersonate

```
    Dim impersonationContext As WindowsImpersonationContext = Nothing
    Dim userHandle As IntPtr = IntPtr.Zero
    Dim fAccess As New FAccess.clsFAccess

    Try
        If LogonUser("my.user", "domain", "password", 2, 0, userHandle) Then

            If userHandle <> IntPtr.Zero Then
                impersonationContext = WindowsIdentity.Impersonate(userHandle)
                    shell("cmd.exe", AppWinStyle.NormalFocus, True)                   
                End Using
            End If
        End If

    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.ToString)
        MsgBox(ex.Message)
    Finally
        If impersonationContext IsNot Nothing Then
            impersonationContext.Undo()
        End If

        If userHandle <> IntPtr.Zero Then
            Marshal.FreeHGlobal(userHandle)
        End If
    End Try
```

I just want to ask, did shell that I call always as user login windows?

*I also try to execute cmd with ProcessStartInfo, it always say 'Directory Failed' or 'File not Found' or 'Access Denied'

Comment: The legacy Shell() function is too primitive to control this.  You need to use the .NET Process class, the ProcessStartInfo.LoadUserProfile property matters.  It also has the UserName property so you don't have to corrupt your own process state with impersonation anymore.

Comment: I'm sorry, I want to ask LoadUserProfile.
From this documentation [link] https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.processstartinfo.loaduserprofile(v=vs.110).aspx  
It says that Function will be load from registry. If I do Impersonate, did the process on impersonate will set profile data from registry that will be loaded by LoadUserProfile function?
I'm just curious, because when I use ProcessStartInfo it's always 'Access Denied'. Anyway thanks for the direction

Answer (score 0):

I found that Runas process can not perform under impersonate,
So I take out the runas process under impersonate

And it's work for me.